# Using a virtual layer, display polygons based on location of another polygon layer

Tags: qgis, sql, virtual-layer

QGIS 3.4

I have a .gml file of every freehold title in a city outlined red below. I want to create a virtual layer of the freeholds which are contained within the blue-green isochrones. Even if a small portion of the freehold title intersects the isochrone, I need the entire freehold to be displayed.

[image]
[image]

my code so far:

```
SELECT *
FROM Freeholds, Isochrones
WHERE st_within(Freeholds.geometry, Isochrones.geometry) = 1
```

I am a novice at SQL and recieve the error 'Referenced table Freeholds in query not found!' How can I correct the query?

Comment: Note that you explicitly do *not* want `ST_Within`, but `ST_Intersects`! You need to import the layers in the top section of the *Virtual Layer* dialog, and use the then displayed name exactly; use `""` enclosing for names with characters other than lower case letters.

Comment: @ThingumaBob cheers, seems I just needed to import the layers...following other guides they managed to perform simple queries without importing file paths which was misleading me. By all means post an answer and I'll accept

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- When creating/editing a *Virtual Layer* using either the

  - `<QGIS> | Layer | Create Layer | New Virtual Layer` or
  - `<QGIS> | Layer | Add Layer | Add/Edit Virtual Layer`

  dialogue, you need to `Import` (or `Add` from source) all referenced
  layers in the *Embedded Layers* panel, and use the (editable) names in the SQL;
  it's a good idea to always `""` enclose relation names with
  characters other than `lowercase_123`, e.g. `"tAbLe N@m€"`
- Alternatively, when using the *DB Manager*, you simply need to
  connect to the `Virtual Layers` provider in the *Providers* panel and
  refer to the layer names as seen in e.g. the `Project Layers` tab.
  Layers created via the *DB Manager* are automatically considered a
  *Virtual Layer*.

---

Use `ST_Intersects` instead of `ST_Within` to include freeholds sharing only a portion with the isochrone polygons.